# Storing large amounts of text in Core Data

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, core-data

I'm trying to see what the best way to store large amounts of text (more than 255 characters) in Cocoa would be. Being a big fan of Core Data, I would assume there's an effective way to do so. However, I feel like 'string' is the wrong data type for this type of thing. Does anyone have any info on this? I don't see an option for BLOB in Core Data

Comment: Have you tried using NSString yet? NSString and Core Data should have no problem handling strings much much bigger than 255 characters.

Comment: @Joe Blow Core Data is backed by SQLite. i.e.: Core Data is "a database job".

Comment: @Joe Blow And you know the OP doesn't require the ORM like capabilities of Core Data based on what? (Other than your own assumption.)

Comment: `NsString` is not that good ide if you are intending to store a large amount of text. You might an error code `1660`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well you can't very well compress the text or store it as a binary that must be translated, otherwise you give up SQLite's querying speed (because all text-stored-as-binary-encoded-data) records must be read into memory, translated/decompressed, then searched). Otherwise, you'd have to mirror (and maintain) the text-only representation in your Core Data store alongside the more full-featured stuff.

How about a hybrid solution? Core Data stores all but the actual text; the text itself is archived a one-file-per-entry-in-Core-Data on the file system. Each file named for its unique identifier in the Core Data store. This way a search could do two things (in the background, of course): search the Core Data store for things like titles, dates, etc; search the files (maybe even with Spotlight) for content search. If there's a file search match, its file name is used to find the matching record in Core Data for display in your app's UI.

This lets you leverage your app-specific internal search criteria *and* Spotlight's programmatic asynchronous search. It's a little more work, granted, but if you're talking about a LOT of text, I can't think of a better way.

Comment: thanks for the feedback josh! I'm just curious- the documentation describes the use of binary for large amounts (KB- to several MB) so would it hurt to use that? It just seems more practical to store the data in Core Data for searching and indexing, and just reliability?

Comment: You will not be able to search for text inside binary information directly in the SQLite store. Each "record" (each instance of the given entity) would need to be read in, decoded (however is appropriate to get your text information), and then searched in memory. VERY inefficient.

Comment: As a bonus, the links-to-external-files approach minimizes the risk of one bad byte hosing your whole document/database. A sizable chunk of meat (the text) is still safe even if the database gets messed up.

Answer (score 2):

The BLOB data type is called "Binary data" in Core Data. As middaparka has pointed out, the [Core Data Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/cocoa/conceptual/CoreData/Articles/cdPerformance.html) offers some guidance on how to deal with binary data in Core Data. Depending on your requirements, an alternative to using BLOBs would be to just store references to files on disk.

Comment: Was going to mention the "on disk, reference in DB" option, but he'll need to manually ensure that the on disk resources are culled when the object is deleted, as Core Data will obviously only delete the reference.

Comment: Easily handled with a basic NSManagedObject subclass for the entity, responding to the insert/save/delete... methods. I use this approach to create Spotlight-searchable "stubs" of an iTunes-like central database, which is managed by Core Data + SQLite store type.

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend a read of Apple's [Core Data Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/cocoa/conceptual/CoreData/Articles/cdPerformance.html) (specifically the "Core Data Performance" section). This specifically mentions BLOBs (see the "Large Data Objects (BLOBs)" section) and gives some, albeit vague, guidelines.